# Dynamically create a class that implements arbitrary interfaces

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-class-creation

I'm creating a PHP library to extract schema.org structured data out of web pages.

Schema.org features a [multiple inheritance hierarchy](https://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html) that I can only achieve through PHP interfaces:

```php
interface LocalBusiness extends Organization, Place
{
}
```

In addition to that, schema.org allows an object to be of [multiple independent types](https://schema.org/additionalType), for example it can be both a `Book` and a `Product`, and use properties from both:

```html
<!-- Uses both the "Book" and "Product" item types -->
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" resource="#record" typeof="Book Product">
...
<span property="author">
...
<span property="sku">
```

To support this use case, I need to dynamically generate classes that implement more than one interface. In the example above, this could look like:

```php
new class implements Book, Product
{
  use BookTrait;
  use ProductTrait;
}
```

I can obviously not generate all interface combinations ahead of time, so I'm thinking of a way to generate such an implementation at runtime.

As far as I know, reflection does not allow to do this kind of things, so the only way I can think of is using generated code and `eval()`, like mocking libraries do. The problem is, **`eval()` can be disabled**, which is an issue when writing a general-purpose library.

Did I overlook something? **Is there another way to dynamically create an object that implements an arbitrary number of interfaces, that are only known at runtime?**

Comment: What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Currently 7.3, I don't mind switching to 7.4 as soon as it's released.